# Missing Native Python Console under Plugin Menu (QGIS 3.20)

Tags: python, qgis-3

I'm unable to locate the native Python Console Menu in QGIS (3.20.0). From everything that I have read, it is supposed to be under the Plugin Menu.

Edit - `ctrl + alt + P`  doesn't bring up the console.

[image: Missing Option for the Python Console]

Python was already installed on the PC as I programme with PyCharm. Could this possibly cause a conflict?

[image: My QGIS About Information]

Comment: the shortcut is `ctrl + alt + P`. At least you can see if the console works or not

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, that doesn't work. Forgot to add that to the initial post.

Comment: Can you see the "Python console" item in Settings --> Interface Customization (and searching by "python")? Chances are it's there but unchecked.

Comment: Thanks. Searching for "Python console" brings up a blank list, while searching for "Python" brings up ``` Widgets -> QgsFieldsProperties -> label_3 (Python Init function)```.